Can managed package be installed in production without AppExchange listing and Security Review?
Can managed package be installed in production without  AppExchange listing and Security Review?

Yes, as long as the Managed Package has been uploaded as "Release" mode (1GP) or has been promoted (2GP). The release/promotion process requires 75% code coverage with zero errors. Note that Managed Packages that aren't submitted through the Partner Program for a Security Review are only legally usable with orgs a particular organization has control over. It's okay to have two sister orgs that use a Managed Package developed by an organization, but it's not legal to distribute a Managed Package to your clients or subscribers, with or without licensing fees, without first becoming a Partner and passing a Security Review.

Technically correct. Note, however, that if the package is sold to the subscriber then this could be considered as violating the master agreement between the ISV and Salesforce.

@PhilW I edited my answer to reflect that, though I feel most non-Security-Reviewed packages are likely used internally, rather than destined to be sold to subscribers as a side-channel bypassing the Partner Program.
